# Post-Processing not showing in game mode (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

there!
I've just started using URP to use post-processing. I've decided to mess with bloom effect first. It seems to be working in Scene view, but when I enter Game mode bloom completely disappears.
Any ideas what causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you've enabled the [Render Post-Processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzCav.png) tick on Camera Settings?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem with bloom using URP, maybe this help you or anyone reading this. i am using unity 2021.3.8.f1. I just go to Edit > Project Settings > Quality. I had my project set to Performant, like this:
[quality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olytW.png)
i clicked on the arrow bellow, on the column of "window, mac, linux" and select Balanced as default and the bloom worked, then switch back to Performant as default and the bloom was still working. So i guess is a bug of unity. I hope this helps to someone. Good luck in your projects! :)

edit: i did not test it in build :/

Answer (score 0):

I enabled hdr in my URP settings and ticked the post processing check on the camera

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was working with URP and a VR project, the camera hierarchy had a parent camera and child cameras, applying to the parent and child fixed my issue.